# How to get the lowest weekly price date?

Tags: pine-script, trading

How can I get the date of the lowest value from last week?

I know to find the price this way:

```
low = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low)
```

however how can I get its date?

how can I work with dates, example:

I want to add to this date + 25 days...
will it give the result I want?

**16/05/2020 + 25 = 11/06/2020**

Please let me know,and thank you in advance!

**Update**:

```
pwl = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1], lookahead=true)
plotshape(pwl, style=shape.labelup, location=location.bottom, color=#FFB500, size=size.normal, text="low", textcolor=color.black)
```

Somehow this plots all the days,when in fact I want only the lowest of the week

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-know-the-date-when-a-highest-value-was-found) example. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @BarisYakut I have updated the question,please take a look